# Adding a timepicker to a datepicker

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript, jquery

Has anybody used a time picker in this link?

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

I have already followed the steps in the link, I added the add-on.js file to my component and the css file inside, but when i change this code

```
var x = jQuery(this).attr("size");                  
    jQuery(this).datepicker({ minDate:"0"-120, maxDate: "0"-x,dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd" });
```

to this :

```
var x = jQuery(this).attr("size");                  
    jQuery(this).datetimepicker({ minDate:"0"-120, maxDate: "0"-x,dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd" });
```

nothing happens. I just want to add a timepicker to the datepicker I used from JqueryUI. Does joomla have something to do with this?

I used this code to load the javascript files from the link that I provided above :

```
$doc->addScript(JUri::base().'/components/com_subscription/media/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js');

$doc->addStyleSheet(JUri::base().'/components/com_subscription/media/css/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css');
```

here is a screenshot of the error when the page loads:

[image]

I was confused because from the link that I am following, it just used the .datetimepicker then it works, but when I use mine, it's not functioning.

The screenshot also displays $.ui is undefined, but that code came from the js file which was from the link I am following.

Comment: How are you calling the JS file?

Comment: hello sir, please see my updated post.

Comment: follow-up question: from the link that I provided above, is this possible to use in joomla?

Comment: Yes, it should still work in Joomla. When you view your site, are you getting any errors in the browser console log? Press F12 and check

Comment: I updated my post again, please see screenshot. I was confused because from the link that I am following, it just used the .datetimepicker then it works, but when I use mine, it's not functioning.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what the issue may be, you need to wrap your code around jquery's document ready like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var x = $(this).attr("size");                  
    $(this).datetimepicker({ minDate:"0"-120, maxDate: "0"-x,dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd" });
});
```

Note that I have used `jQuery(document)` (the global scope) and then used `function($)` so that the dollar symbol is an alias. This will prevent possible conflicts.

#### Update:

You also need to ensure you're importing jQuery UI which you can do using Joomla's built in methods like so:

```
<?php
    JHtml::_('jquery.ui');
?>
```

Comment: I'm afraid my code is already wrapped around a document ready function but still the error exists.. datetimepicker is not a function.

Comment: Try using my document ready please and let me know if you still have any issues

Comment: the error is still the same sir.

Comment: Please provide the **full** code you're using and put it in http://pastebin.com/ so I can see it

Comment: http://pastebin.com/kjRydZgi

here is the code

Comment: I'm just going through the code. Does all this code belong in 1 single file, or is it from multiple files?

Comment: it is a view file. default.php all codes belong in one file only.

Comment: @BreaktheLaw - Try replacing all your code with this. No changes, simply copy it all. (make sure you backup your current file first): http://pastebin.com/muHtfvq9

Comment: You will see that I've only imported the `.min` CSS and JS files so make sure they exist